# Как подобрать размер шрифта, чтобы строка была определенной ширины

Tags: qt, c++

Приветствую. Необходимо, чтобы текст максимально занимал выделенную область ( по ширине ). Собственно, решил вопрос в лоб:

```
void ModernViewer::adjustFontSize( QFont &font, int width, const QString &text )
{
    QFontMetrics fm( font );

    int fontSize = -1;

    do {
        ++fontSize;
        font.setPointSize( fontSize + 1 );
        fm = QFontMetrics( font );
    } while( fm.width( text ) <= width );

    font.setPointSize( fontSize );
}
```

Вот как используется:

```
void ModernViewer::drawGameOver()
{
    int left   = CELL_SIZE,
        top    = CELL_SIZE,
        width  = ( m_dataModel->width() - 2 ) * CELL_SIZE,
        height = ( m_dataModel->height() - 2 ) * CELL_SIZE;

    QFont font( "Arial Black", 0, 99 );
    QString text = tr( "GAME OVER" );

    adjustFontSize( font, width, text );

    QPainter painter( this );

    painter.setFont( font );
    painter.setPen( Qt::green );

    painter.drawText( left, top, width, height, Qt::AlignCenter, text );
}
```

Как это сделать проще и красивее?

Answer (score 2):

Разве что делать шаги не по 1, а переменными, с последовательным приближением к нужному результату. [link text](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_mathematics/4230/ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫХ)

Comment: вообще-то, это называется "двоичный поиск" :)